# R and ggplot2: How to create a graph with three elements?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddk4F.jpg). After some thought, I have created a dummy data frame that I think might be somewhat akin to what I need:

```
dum = structure(list(pan = c(4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000), core = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 2500, 2600, 2700), Group = c("Bac1", "Bac2", "Bac3", "Bac4", "Bac5", "Bac6"), Strain = c(1000L, 50L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 10L)), .Names = c("pan", "core", "Group", "Strain"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've been using this code:

```
 ggplot(dum, aes(x=Group,y = Strain)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   geom_line(aes(y = pan, colour = "pan")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = core, colour = "core"))
```

Which produces this incorrect [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffzIv.png).

What is going wrong here? I can't understand why the pan and core elements of the graph are not showing up. Are they being negated by the `geom_bar` command?

Comment: Hallo @E.O. if the solution is ok can you mark it as such please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add `group=1` to aes.

```
ggplot(dum, aes(x=Group,y = Strain, group = 1)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(aes(y = pan, colour = "pan")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = core, colour = "core"))
```

[image: result]

The data points must be grouped so it knows which points to connect.(regarding line graphs)